# android service or custom implementation of MediaPlayer, which is better?

Tags: android, service, focus, media-player

I am using android MediaPlayer class and one of the activities of this app has play, pause, and select mp3, buttons.   The app has 4 activities total. I am able to get it to work for the one activity. however when I leave by using the back button or go to another activity after pressing a button to go to the other activity, the media player does not keep playing when I leave the activity.

I wanted the music to keep playing across all activities for this app, but not outside of the app. and to be able to have pause buttons on other activities to pause that same track of music.  But I did not think that a service was the best way because it would play when the app is out of focus.  Like when someone is looking at some other app while this app is not visible.  What I understand is that a service is more for music to run in the background even if your app is not visible to the user.

The first choice is to code the MediaPlayer so that it will run across all of the activities in this one application but not outside of the application.  The second choice is to use an android service in a way that it can be confined to this one app if that is possible.

Of the two choices, which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service is better. This is what you can do to solve your problem. You can run the service for your application to play music.

For example if you have four activities A->B->C->D.When you come back at the the root activity A from which you are supposed to stop the mediaplayer(so it doesnot play outside the app) you can just stop your service in the onStop()

Here is the developer reference for the service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html  (fixed link)

And here is a indepth tutorial regarding the services from Lars Vogel
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: thank you. i will use a service. that looks like the best choice